# Can Juju connect services that are in different environments?

Tags: juju, maas, kvm-virtualization, openstack

Background: I'm trying to get Openstack working with Juju. I'm testing it, so I either have to use KVM virtualization or LXC because I only have one (powerful) machine. I would prefer to use LXC because it's lighter and faster. But some openstack charms need to format /dev/sdb or insert a kernel module or mount a drive, and will fail to deploy in LXC.

So, is it possible to deploy some Openstack services in LXC and some on KVM virtual machines that are managed by MaaS and add relations between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for we call "cross environment relations", and unfortunately we do not support that yet. Here's the bug report for it if you want to follow along though:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1049340

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly, the answer should be yes, soon, on MAAS.

The container addressability story is currently only good on MAAS.  However soon, we hope to have KVM working alongside LXC.

Comment: To make sure I understand the answer: What machine are you talking about the LXC containers running on? The machine that the juju client is on, where you can use the lxc provider?